# Golang write net.Dial response to the browser

Tags: tcp, go

I am playing with the net package, and i want to make a simple proxy.
First i make a listener on localhost, then i dial the remote address

```
remote, err := net.Dial("tcp", "google.com:80")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer remote.Close()

fmt.Fprint(remote, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
```

How can i pipe the response to the browser? Or do i need to work with the default webserver and copy the response body? I really want to try it with net package or something

thx

Comment: You're doing this in the context of an http request, or if you're rewriting the http stack from scratch, a TCP connection, right? Both a TCP connection and an HTTP response are `Writer` interface implementors. So just write to either with `Fprintf`  - `w.Write([]byte(err.String()))` instead of calling `log.Fatal`

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://bytbox.net/blog/2013/01/trivial-http-proxy-golang.html) simple proxy implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy the connection from the remote is used 2 goroutines with io.Copy

```
func copyContent(from, to net.Conn, done chan bool) {
    _, err := io.Copy(from, to)
    if err != nil {
        done <- true
    }
 done <- true
}

// in the main func
done := make(chan bool, 2)
go copyContent(conn, remote, done)
go copyContent(remote, conn, done)
<-done
<-done
```